# Mongoose : Find and Update Multiple Nested Documents

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

My Documents are as follows.

```
{
    "order_id" : "1",
    "payment_status" : false,
    "items" : [
        {
            "item_id" : 1,
            "payment_status" : false,
        },
        {
            "item_id" : 2,
            "payment_status" : false,
        },
        {
            "item_id" : 3,
            "payment_status" : false,
        },
    ]
}
```

I need to update the fields `payment_status` for  `{"order_id":1}` and `{"item_id" : 1}` and `{"item_id" : 3}`. Also, I need to update the same in bulk for matching conditions. Is this possible in mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using [$arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#specify-arrayfilters-for-array-update-operations) like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  "order_id": "1"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "items.$[item].payment_status": true
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "item.item_id": {
        $in: [
          1,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yk8QfEADcvh)

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working in Mongo Playground. I will check the same in my code and post an update soon